# How to set selected on existing list of options in jQuery-MultiSelect

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, dropdown, html-select

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(x => Model.Materials, Model.Materials, new { id = "listBoxMaterial" })
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var product = $('#listBoxMaterial').multiselect({
            search   : true,
            selectAll: true
        });
        var SelectedMaterials = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.SelectedMaterials));
        if(SelectedMaterials != null){                
            var _selectedMaterials = SelectedMaterials.split(",")
            var options = [];
            $(_selectedMaterials).each(function(i){
                var item = new Object();
                item.name = _selectedMaterials[i];
                item.value = _selectedMaterials[i];
                item.checked = true;
                options.push(item);
            });
            product.multiselect('loadOptions', options, false, true);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Code is using https://github.com/nobleclem/jQuery-MultiSelect plugin
I want to set selected value on existing list of options.

I am looking at

> loadOptions( options, overwrite, updateSelect )
>
> Update options of select list. Default state will replace existing list with this one.
>
> -Set the second parameter to false to append to the list. (default = true)
> -Set the third parameter to false to leave the native select list as is. (default = true)

I don't want to overwrite, neither append to existing list.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#your-select').multiSelect('select', String|Array);
```

```
$('#your-select').multiSelect('refresh');
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @John Where do you get the refresh option? I cannot find it in their page https://github.com/nobleclem/jQuery-MultiSelect